# Is there a possibility of parallel write into Parquet from python/pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, parquet

Parquet file format allows data partitioning. 
There's also a quite recent project `fastparquet` that provides python implementation. The question is if I have two dataframes with the same schema in two separate python processes is there a possibility to store them in parallel in two separate partitions of parquet file?

Answer (score 1):

there is.

- It is possible to do with [fastparquet](http://fastparquet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) solely (using `merge()` function to read separately written dataframes).
- It is also possible with `dask` `to_parquet()` which uses fastparquet under the hood.

Comment: This sounds like exactly what I'm interested in. Do you have a code example of how the fastparquet alone option works? I'm not sure which `merge()` function you're referring to.

Answer (score 0):

Writing Parquet files in parallel is easy with [Dask](https://mungingdata.com/dask/read-csv-to-parquet/), PySpark, and [Koalas](https://mungingdata.com/python/writing-parquet-pandas-pyspark-koalas/).

It'd also be possible with PyArrow if multiple cores were configured to write file in parallel.

Now that Arrow has a 1.0 release, I'd recommend using PyArrow over fastparquet.